# Planned telescope to detect alien waste-heat

Tags: exoplanet, observational-astronomy, telescope

I remember watching a talk by someone who designed a telescope to view a single star at a time.

The purpose of the telescope was to detect waste-heat which would presumably be emitted by any civilization utilizing a large percentage of their planet's solar energy, due to the second law of thermodynamics. By focusing on a single star, it would be able to detect when the planet crossed the path of star-light, and the additional energy emitted by the planet - or something like this.

Anyone know who this might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be the [SETI's Colossus telescope project](http://www.the-colossus.com/), that aims to build a high-resolution, multiple-mirror instrument with ability to directly image the heat generated by other civilizations on planets orbiting stars near us:

[image: SETI's Colossus telescope]

<sup>Artist's impression of the proposed SETI's Colossus Telescope (Credit: Innovative Optics/Colossus Corporation)</sup>

> As Earth-like civilizations evolve, they use more power. For example,
>   in Roman times, we estimate Ω [the ratio of a civilization’s power production to the amount of solar power it receives] was about 1/1000 what it is today.
>   Humans’ global power consumption is growing by about 2.5 percent per
>   year, even though the world’s population is growing at less than half
>   this rate. In contrast, our knowledge base (the combined total of all
>   recorded information) doubles in just two years. As cultures advance,
>   their information content also must grow, and the power required to
>   manipulate this knowledge eventually dominates a civilization’s total
>   power use.
>
> Using a sensitive coronagraph to remove scattered light that would
>   obscure an exoplanet, Colossus would be able to find hundreds of
>   Earth-sized or larger planets in the habitable zone including any
>   civilizations on their surfaces.
>
> <sup>Source: [Paul Gilster for Centauri Dreams](http://www.centauri-dreams.org/?p=27867) quoting Jeff Kuhn (University of Hawaii), Svetlana V. Berdyugina (University of Freiburg), David Halliday (Dynamic Structures, Ltd., in British Columbia), and Caisey Harlingten (Searchlight Observatory Network, Norwich, England)</sup>

Here is a Jeff Kuhn's, Institute for Astronomy, University of Hawaii, talk on [The Colossus Telescope and the search for ET](http://www.seti.org/weeky-lecture/colossus-project), and a quite descriptive blog post by Brian Wang on [Technology for 77 meter primary mirror ground based telescope exists today and it could survey earth sized exoplanets out to 60 light years](http://nextbigfuture.com/2013/06/technology-for-77-meter-primary-mirror.html) advocating the project from a technology perspective.

A bit more can also be read on the [Innovative Optics Ltd.](http://www.innovativeoptics.ca/) web pages, that are sadly under construction, but they do give a hint that an article about it was written in [June 2013 edition of the Astronomy Magazine](http://www.astronomy.com/issues/2013/june-2013), titled *[How to find ET with infrared light](http://www.astronomy.com/~/media/Files/PDF/Magazine%20articles/ET-with-infrared-light.pdf)* (PDF), by Jeff R Kuhn, Svetlana V Berdyugina, David Halliday, Caisey Harlingten. A nice digest is also available in [this Centauri Dreams blog post](http://www.centauri-dreams.org/?p=27867).

Comment: Ah yes, I think that is the talk, thank you!